# Securing a Docker container with HTTP BASIC AUTH

Tags: security, authentication, nginx, docker

Consider running a Docker container with a web application exposing a certain port. How to apply the additional security layer before accessing the URL (HTTP BASIC AUTH)?

Docker Engine version >= 1.9.1

Comment: httpd with basic auth - https://github.com/koolwithk/devops-tools/tree/main/docker/httpd-basic-auth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, you dedicate a container for authentication, with for instance NGiNX.
This is described in "[Authenticating proxy with nginx](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/blob/main/docs/recipes/nginx.md)", which not only adds the basic authentication, but also ssl (https)

That web server will then reverse proxy to your container.

You have a more generic solution (based on a reverse-proxy NGiNX) with [`jwilder/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

> nginx-proxy sets up a container running nginx and **[`docker-gen`](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen)**.
> `docker-gen` generates reverse proxy configs for nginx and reloads nginx when containers are started and stopped.

See the use case with "[Automated Nginx Reverse Proxy for Docker](http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/)".

Answer (score 6):

Here is a config example based on the instructions from [jwilder/nginx-proxy Basic Auth support](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#basic-authentication-support):

The `docker-compose.yml` file (to be used by running `docker-compose up -d`):

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    networks: 
      - proxynet
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/nginx/htpasswd:/etc/nginx/htpasswd
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

networks:
  proxynet:
    external: true
```

And here is a simple container that uses that proxy for the domain name [www.example.com](http://www.example.com):

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   example:
     container_name: www.example.com
     image: php:7.2-apache
     restart: always
     networks:
       - proxynet
     expose:
       - "80"
     environment:
       - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.example.com
       - VIRTUAL_PORT=80

networks:
  proxynet:
    external: true
```

Under `/srv/docker/nginx/htpasswd/`, place a `www.example.com` file, containing:

```
test:wTVo4pnGgDWBo
```

Accessing `http://www.example.com` (to be replaced with your actual domain name), you'll then be prompted for a username and a password (`test:test` in this case).

Comment: Interesting example, which illustrates my own answer. +1

Comment: I am running exactly that code, and got error..
`WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. `
`Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'`

Comment: dhparam.pem is indeed mandatory : to automate SSL certificates generation, you might have a look at the excellent https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion